# How to replace value in matrix with NA if corresponding value is NA

Tags: r

Can somebody advise:-
Consider the following

```r
X <- c(2,5,8,12,7)
Y <- c(4,11,88,NA,66)
Z <- cbind(X,Y)

Z
      X  Y
[1,]  2  4
[2,]  5 11
[3,]  8 88
[4,] 45 NA
[5,]  7 66
```

How can I make `Z[4,1]` to be equal `NA` if, as in this case `Z[4,2]` is equal `NA`. What I want to return is :-

```
      X  Y
[1,]  2  4
[2,]  5 11
[3,]  8 88
[4,] NA NA
[5,]  7 66
```

Comment: Do you want to apply this to all columns if there are more than two?

Comment: Try `Z[,1] <-  Z[,1]*NA^is.na(Z[,2])`

Comment: Another idea: `Z[rowSums(is.na(Z)) >= 1, ] <- NA`

Comment: Wokded perfect Mike Thank you